# Display a for loop output?

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, struct

When printing out the result I get the deck of cards for each player I want but when finding who has 2 clubs, instead of printing on the bottom of the console it prints under the players deck. I have no clue how to get this on the bottom unless I create another function. Any way of getting this to print out who has 2 clubs on the bottom of the console?

```
void CardClass::PrintCards(CardType *player) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    if (player[i].suit == DIAMOND)
      cout << " Diamond" << setw(11);
    if (player[i].suit == CLUB)
      cout << " Club" << setw(14);
    if (player[i].suit == SPADE)
      cout << " Spade" << setw(13);
    if (player[i].suit == HEART)
      cout << " Heart" << setw(13);
    if (player[i].value == 2)
      cout << "2" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 3)
      cout << "3" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 4)
      cout << "4" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 5)
      cout << "5" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 6)
      cout << "6" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 7)
      cout << "7" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 8)
      cout << "8" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 9)
      cout << "9" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 10)
      cout << "10" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 11)
      cout << "J" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 12)
      cout << "Q" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 13)
      cout << "K" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].value == 14)
      cout << "A" << setw(15);
    if (player[i].points == 0)
      cout << "0" << endl;
    if (player[i].points == 5)
      cout << "5" << endl;
    if (player[i].points == 10)
      cout << "10" << endl;
    if (player[i].points == 100)
      cout << "100" << endl;
    if (player[i].points == -100)
      cout << "-100" << endl;
  }
  
  for(int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    if (player[i].suit == CLUB && player[i].value == 2)
      cout << "has the 2 clubs" << endl;
  }
}
```

output:

```
PLAYER 1

  SUIT          VALUE         POINTS
 Diamond          6              0
 Diamond          9              0
 Club             3              0
 Club             A              0
 Club             6              0
 Club             2              0
 Club             5              0
 Heart            Q             10
 Heart            4              5
 Heart            K             10
 Spade            K              0
 Spade            3              0
 Spade            9              0
has the 2 clubs
PLAYER 2

  SUIT          VALUE         POINTS
 Diamond          4              0
 Diamond          K              0
 Diamond          J           -100
 Diamond         10              0
 Diamond          Q              0
 Club            10              0
 Heart            J             10
 Heart            5              5
 Heart            2              5
 Spade            4              0
 Spade            2              0
 Spade            Q            100
 Spade            8              0
PLAYER 3

  SUIT          VALUE         POINTS
 Diamond          5              0
 Diamond          A              0
 Diamond          7              0
 Diamond          3              0
 Diamond          2              0
 Club             J              0
 Club             7              0
 Heart            9              5
 Heart            A             10
 Spade           10              0
 Spade            A              0
 Spade            J              0
 Spade            5              0
PLAYER 4

  SUIT          VALUE         POINTS
 Diamond          8              0
 Club             K              0
 Club             4              0
 Club             Q              0
 Club             9              0
 Club             8              0
 Heart            3              5
 Heart            7              5
 Heart           10             10
 Heart            6              5
 Heart            8              5
 Spade            7              0
 Spade            6              0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the information about who has 2 of clubs inside your `CardClass::PrintCards` function. If you print it there - you are going to see it right after that player's hand.

If you want to save it and print later - you need to return some information to a calling function. For example:

```
bool CardClass::PrintCards(CardType *player) {
  ...
  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    if (player[i].suit == CLUB && player[i].value == 2)
      return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```